# Change JS scrolling event to time interval

Tags: javascript

I have an image gallery I'm using for a webpage. Currently, the gallery images change when the user scrolls, but I'd like to change it so that the images change on a time interval, and are on a loop instead of an up scroll to go back and a down scroll to go forward. I'm pretty new to Javascript, so I'm now sure how to change the below script from scrolling to timed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var curPage = 1;
  var numOfPages = $(".skw-page").length;
  var animTime = 1000;
  var scrolling = false;
  var pgPrefix = ".skw-page-";

  function pagination() {
    scrolling = true;

  $(pgPrefix + curPage).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
  $(pgPrefix + (curPage - 1)).addClass("inactive");
  $(pgPrefix + (curPage + 1)).removeClass("active");

  setTimeout(function() {
    scrolling = false;
  }, animTime);
};

  function navigateUp() {
    if (curPage === 1) return;
    curPage--;
    pagination();
  };

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage === numOfPages) return;
    curPage++;
    pagination();
  };

  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
    if (scrolling) return;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      navigateUp();
    } else { 
      navigateDown();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (scrolling) return;
    if (e.which === 38) {
      navigateUp();
    } else if (e.which === 40) {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), change what happens when `navigateDown` is called once all pages have been cycled through, and remove the scroll/keydown listeners.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var curPage = 1;
  var numOfPages = $(".skw-page").length;
  var animTime = 1000;
  var scrolling = false;
  var pgPrefix = ".skw-page-";

  function pagination() {
    scrolling = true;

    $(pgPrefix + curPage)
      .removeClass("inactive")
      .addClass("active");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage - 1)).addClass("inactive");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage + 1)).removeClass("active");
    if (curPage === 1) $(pgPrefix + numOfPages).addClass("inactive");

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrolling = false;
    }, animTime);
  }

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage === numOfPages) curPage = 0;
    curPage++;
    console.log(curPage);
    pagination();
  }

  setInterval(navigateDown, 5000); // 5000 ms == 5 s
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: purple;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p class="skw-page skw-page-1 active">Page 1</p>
  <p class="skw-page skw-page-2 inactive">Page 2</p>
  <p class="skw-page skw-page-3 inactive">Page 3</p>
  <p class="skw-page skw-page-4 inactive">Page 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This mostly works, except when ```navigateDown``` gets to the last image, it cycles up to the next to last image instead of the first one, and then gets stuck looping between those two

Comment: @kdubs how many pages are there, and is the first page number `1` or `0`

Comment: there are 4 pages and the first number is 1. I tried changing ```curPage = 0``` to ```curPage = 1``` in the ```navigateDown()``` function you posted but got the same behavior

Comment: @kdubs I've updated the snippet, see if that works now

Comment: Close - I figured it out. The 4th image kept ```active``` when the function cycled back to 1. I updated it to remove active as well as add inactive and now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), also **inside `setInterval` you should not call both the navigateUp and navigateDown functions**, since this will nullify their pagination changes as defined in your code.

Also, since in your original code, the trigger to fire either of navigateDown and nvaigateUp functions depends on event passed from `keydown` and `DOMmouseScroll`, you will need to tweak my example code to fit your html. I can not give a complete example since your `html` part is missing here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var curPage = 1;
  var numOfPages = $(".skw-page").length;
  var animTime = 1000;
  var scrolling = false;
  var pgPrefix = ".skw-page-";

  function pagination() {
    scrolling = true;

    $(pgPrefix + curPage).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage - 1)).addClass("inactive");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage + 1)).removeClass("active");

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrolling = false;
    }, animTime);
  }

  function navigateUp() {
    if (curPage === 1) return;
    curPage--;
    pagination();
  }

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage === numOfPages) return;
    curPage++;
    pagination();
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    navigateUp();
    /*
    or call
    navigateDown();
    */
  }, animTime);
});
```